# Postgres: insert random boolean value into field?

Tags: postgresql

I am working in Postgres 9.4. I have a table with a boolean field called `include_in_rct`, and with about 5000 rows. I would like to randomly assign this value as true or false on all existing rows, with a 50% probability in either direction. Can I do this in Postgres?

I need to do something like:

```
UPDATE mytable SET include_in_rct(<random boolean>)
```

Or I could set the value to False for every row, then do something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET include_in_rct(FALSE)
UPDATE mytable SET include_in_rct(TRUE) WHERE id IN <some random set of 50% of IDs>
```

What's the best approach?

Comment: `WHERE random()>0.5` should work, if it provides proper random values

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I can think of two ways:

First using `random()`

```
update mytable
  set include_in_rct = random() > 0.5;
```

This will not necessarily have an **exact** 50% distribution.

To get an exact 50/50 distribution you can use:

```
update mytable
  set include_in_rct = (rn % 2 = 0)
from (
  select id, row_number() over ( order by random() ) as rn
  from mytable
) x
where x.id = mytable.id;
```

This assumes that `id` is the primary key of that table.

The first one will however be faster, but for only 5000 rows it won't matter.

Comment: The second example won't update random rows, it'll update every even row in its current state. However, an `row_number() over (order by random())` could possibly update random rows with 50% distribution (I know it won't be super effective, but in case of 5000 rows, it doesn't matter much).

Comment: @pozs: well the second statement will update the rows with a 50% distribution of false and true values - but yes it's not "random"

Answer (score 7):

Always K.I.S.S.

```
select round(random());
```

For the question:

```
select (round(random())::int)::boolean;
```

Comment: > ERROR: column "x" is of type boolean but expression is of type double precision

Comment: `round(random())::int::boolean` should work